# Hibernate Criteria for list

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, contains

Good Day,

I have a Hibernate mapping that looks something like this:

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
      private lond id;
      private String Name;
      private boolean status;
      ...

}

public class ItemHolder  implements Serializable {
      private long id;
      private List<Item> items;
      ...
}
```

How can I do query to get all Item Holder's witch contains my Item?
(with criteria)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need a join:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(ItemHolder.class, "itemHolder");
c.createAlias("itemHolder.items", "item");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("item.id", theItemId);
```

Comment: This is OK, but can answer duplicate ItemHolders if the item criteria matches more than once. For example -- if searching for Items by wildcard name.

Answer (score 2):

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(ItemHolder.class);
criteria.createAlias("items", "item"); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("item.Name", "my Item").ignoreCase());
```

you can restrict with your requirement : id or name..

Answer (score 1):

The query could be something like:

```
Item loadedItem = ...;
Query query = session.createQuery("from ItemHolder ih where :item in elements(ih.items)");
query.setParameter("item", loadedItem);
List list = query.list();
```